# How to mkdir only if a directory does not already exist?

Tags: shell, scripting, ksh, aix, mkdir

I am writing a shell script to run under the KornShell (ksh) on AIX. I would like to use the `mkdir` command to create a directory. But the directory may already exist, in which case I do not want to do anything. So I want to either test to see that the directory does not exist, or suppress the "File exists" error that `mkdir` throws when it tries to create an existing directory.

How can I best do this?

Answer (score 4701, accepted):

Try [`mkdir -p`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/mkdir.html):

```
mkdir -p foo
```

Note that this will also create any intermediate directories that don't exist; for instance,

```
mkdir -p foo/bar/baz
```

will create directories `foo`, `foo/bar`, and `foo/bar/baz` if they don't exist.

Some implementation like GNU `mkdir` include `mkdir --parents` as a more readable alias, but this is not specified in POSIX/Single Unix Specification and not available on many common platforms like macOS, various BSDs, and various commercial Unixes, so it should be avoided.

If you want an error when parent directories don't exist, and want to create the directory if it doesn't exist, then you can [`test`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/test.html) for the existence of the directory first:

```
[ -d foo ] || mkdir foo
```

Comment: the shortened example you use is exactly what you should not do.  It is reversing the logic to save coding space but it should use ! and && and make more sense to those reading it.

Comment: On Windows8 it seems -p is no longer supported and it's the default behavior.

Comment: @AndreasLarsen This question is about `mkdir` on Unix-like systems, not on Windows. `-p` is required for POSIX/Single Unix Specification compliance, so anything that intents to comply with those specifications will support `-p`. Windows is entirely different, unless you use a POSIX emulation layer like Cygwin or MSYS.

Comment: I discovered something interesting today with `mkdir -p`, you can use brackets! `{}` to create "complex" directory tree in a command. See here: http://technosophos.com/2010/04/15/mkdir-creating-multiple-subdirectories-one-command.html

Comment: @MikeQ I 'd prefer ```||``` instead of ```&&``` because then the whole line has the right exit status. Important if your shell runs with ```errexit``` or if that line is the last one in a function, switch-case, whatever.

Comment: Or: `mkdir somedir 2>/dev/null || true`

Comment: @herve That has nothing to do with `mkdir`; the shell expands such an expression to a discrete list of argument that are passed to `mkdir`.

Comment: Does this work with a wild card before the intermediate steps? Ex /*/foo/bar/baz ?

Comment: @akozi Yes, if the appropriate directories already exist at the level that the wild card is used. In the shell, glob expansion happens before passing the arguments to the program (`mkdir`, in this case). So if you had directories `a`, `b`, and `c`, `mkdir -p */foo/bar/baz` would be the same as `mkdir -p a/foo/bar/baz b/foo/bar/baz c/foo/bar/baz`. `mkdir` can take multiple arguments, and when given `-p`, it will create needed intermediate directories. Experiment with this yourself. Try `echo mkdir -p */foo/bar/baz` to see what command is run; or just try running it in a test directory.

Comment: @herve discovery is very handy. Please remember not to leave whitespaces in any part of this script.

Comment: @herve Awesome! Just realized it works for other commands as well, e.g. to create 3 files: `touch {a,b,c}.txt`

Comment: I prefer `[ -d foo ] || mkdir foo`. 

Comment: For the case that foo may be a symlink to a folder: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793858/how-to-mkdir-only-if-a-directory-does-not-already-exist/73223179#73223179

Answer (score 258):

This should work:

```
$ mkdir -p dir
```

or:

```
if [[ ! -e $dir ]]; then
    mkdir $dir
elif [[ ! -d $dir ]]; then
    echo "$dir already exists but is not a directory" 1>&2
fi
```

which will create the directory if it doesn't exist, but warn you if the name of the directory you're trying to create is already in use by something other than a directory.

Comment: I don't think there's a -d operator in korn, rather -e is used for both files / directories and just checks existence. Also, they all return 0 upon success, so ! is redundant. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: wrong on both counts, AFAIK.  tests return _true_ on success, and -d exists too (at least on MacOS X)

Comment: it might be worth mentioning that this isn't quite thread-safe.  between the time that you check if the directory exists and the time you try to write, things might change.

Answer (score 116):

Use the -p flag.

```
man mkdir
mkdir -p foo
```

Comment: -p, --parents
              no error if existing, make parent directories as needed

Answer (score 91):

Defining complex directory trees with one command

```
mkdir -p project/{lib/ext,bin,src,doc/{html,info,pdf},demo/stat/a}
```

Comment: no error if existing, make parent directories as needed

Comment: Keep in mind that this is not a feature of `mkdir` itself, but the shell that executes the command. It's called brace expansion - AFAIK, only Bash, ksh, zsh, and the C shell support it.

Comment: if you have spaces around the commas you may (will) get unexpected result. Beware.

Comment: @Atlas7 stated, you will need to escape characters that are normally part of regex. (i.e. instead of using `folder name` you need to use `folder\ name`)

Comment: This is not an answer; this is a separate topic that would be more appropriate as a comment.

Comment: *Defining*? Do you mean *creating*?

Answer (score 55):

If you don't want to show any error message:

```
[ -d newdir ] || mkdir newdir
```

If you want to show your own error message:

```
[ -d newdir ] && echo "Directory Exists" || mkdir newdir
```

Comment: But [subject to race conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793858/how-to-mkdir-only-if-a-dir-does-not-already-exist/793916#793916)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen : Of course. Use `mkdir -p` if you do not want race conditions. But you won't get to show your own `Directory exists` error.

Answer (score 49):

`mkdir foo` works even if the directory exists.
To make it work only if the directory named "foo" does not exist, try using the `-p` flag.

Example:

```
mkdir -p foo
```

This will create the directory named "foo" only if it does not exist. :)

Comment: As mentioned by @BrianCampbell, this will also create any other directories in the path. This can be dangerous if e.g. a volume becomes unmounted, as it may create directories in the mount point.

Answer (score 37):

You can either use an `if` statement to check if the directory exists or not. If it does not exits, then create the directory.

1. dir=/home/dir_name

   ```bash
   if [ ! -d $dir ]
   then
        mkdir $dir
   else
        echo "Directory exists"
   fi
   ```
2. You can directory use mkdir with -p option to create a directory. It will check if the directory is not available it will.

   ```bash
   mkdir -p $dir
   ```

   mkdir -p also allows to create the tree structure of the directory. If you want to create the parent and child directories using same command, can opt mkdir -p

   ```bash
   mkdir -p /home/parent_dir /home/parent_dir/child1 /home/parent_dir/child2
   ```

Comment: Is there any advantage in using if loop!? why would someone choose that over -p option?!

Comment: I have shared you ways of creating the folders when an folder does not exists. It depends upon the requirement on the one. If you have a use case where you need to check if folder does not exist and you want to keep track of that so you can go with solution 1. If it does not matter, you can go with solution 2, it will create the folder if not exists.

Answer (score 30):

Simple, silent and deadly:

```
mkdir -p /my/new/dir >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: It should be: mkdir -p /my/new/dir >/dev/null 2>&1

Comment: `mkdir -p my/new/dir` does not complain if `my/new/dir` already exists, no need to redirect output

Comment: Typo fixed.  Leevi, I believe I ran into a situation where the output needed to be squelched.

Comment: note for naiive windows users: `-p` still fails on windows when the folder exists

Comment: Does `mkdir -p /parent/dir` complain if permissions prevent creating /parent/dir ?  If so, perhaps the redirection might be considered "deadly" or at least unwise.

Comment: Sure, you're right, things can always go wrong for a number of reasons.  If you need more requirements met than requested by the OP (permissions, invalid path, out of space...), you should script for them.

Answer (score 27):

The old tried and true

```
mkdir /tmp/qq >/dev/null 2>&1
```

will do what you want with none of the race conditions many of the other solutions have.

Sometimes the simplest (and ugliest) solutions are the best.

Comment: This will fail if "tmp" did not exist. nor does it give you any confirmation.

Comment: Race conditions? Can you elaborate in your answer? Non-atomic test & create?

Comment: @Peter, a snippet like (for example) `[ -d newdir ] || mkdir newdir`, where the directory does not initially exist, has a race condition in that, between the test for existence and the attempted creation, another process could swoop in and create the directory. Hence the `mkdir` would then fail.

Comment: @Mike Q: the base path `/tmp` has likely been chosen in the example to represent a base-path that always exists and is write-able to the current user, e.g. the user has enough rights to create a directory in. You raise a valid point thought:: the logic is a bit contradictory, as when this command fails, it can mean two things: 1.) the directory exists or 2.) the directory could not be created. This is not true for the operation itself, therefore a simple post-check on the directory path can give the confirmation, or the next command that operates on.

Comment: `mkdir -p /tmp/qq > /dev/null 2>&1` will create /tmp/ if missing.

Answer (score 18):

mkdir does not support -p switch anymore on Windows 8+ systems.

You can use this:

```
IF NOT EXIST dir_name MKDIR dir_name
```

Comment: OP was about AIX kornshell... nothing to do with Windows, does it?

Comment: Are you sure it was supported before? Do you have a source?

Answer (score 15):

```
directory_name = "foo"

if [ -d $directory_name ]
then
    echo "Directory already exists"
else
    mkdir $directory_name
fi
```

Answer (score 15):

This is a simple function (Bash shell) which lets you create a directory if it doesn't exist.

```
#------------------------------------------#
# Create a directory if it does not exist. #
#------------------------------------------#
# Note the "-p" option in the mkdir        #
# command which creates directories        #
# recursively.                             #
#------------------------------------------#
createDirectory() {
   mkdir -p -- "$1"
}
```

You can call the above function as:

> createDirectory "$(mktemp -d dir-example.XXXXX)/fooDir/BarDir"

The above creates fooDir and BarDir if they don't exist. Note the "-p" option in the mkdir command which creates directories recursively.

Answer (score 12):

Or if you want to check for existence first:

```
if [[ ! -e /path/to/newdir ]]; then
            mkdir /path/to/newdir
fi
```

**-e** is the exist test for [KornShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KornShell).

You can also try googling a KornShell manual.

Answer (score 12):

Referring to man page `man mkdir` for option -`p`

```
   -p, --parents
          no error if existing, make parent directories as needed
```

which will create all directories in a given path, if exists throws no error otherwise it creates all directories from left to right in the given path. Try the below command. the directories `newdir` and `anotherdir` doesn't exists before issuing this command

**Correct Usage**

`mkdir -p /tmp/newdir/anotherdir`

After executing the command you can see `newdir` and `anotherdir` created under /tmp. You can issue this command as many times you want, the command always have `exit(0)`. Due to this reason most people use this command in shell scripts before using those actual paths.

Answer (score 10):

Improvement on the 'classic' solution (by Brian Campbell) - to handle the case of symlink to a directory.

```
[ -d foo/. ] || mkdir foo
```

Answer (score 5):

```
mkdir -p sam
```

- mkdir = Make Directory
- -p    = --parents
- (no error if existing, make parent directories as needed)

Answer (score 3):

```
if [ !-d $dirName ];then
     if ! mkdir $dirName; then  # Shorter version. Shell will complain if you put braces here though
     echo "Can't make dir: $dirName"
     fi
fi
```