# Ant: scp create directory if not exist

Tags: xml, ant, build

I am using this to copy from A to B.
But if for example the folder /config doesnt exist it gives me an exception. How can I solve it? I tried mkdirs="true" but it runs to error as well

```
<scp todir="${ftplogin}@${ftpserver}:${ftp-remote-dir}/config" verbose="false" trust="true" failonerror="No">
            <fileset dir="${stuff}/${stuff-version}/config${config-files}">
                <include name="*.*"/>               
            </fileset> 
        </scp>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to create remote directories with scp task.
Here's a macrodef for scptransfer, that does all the work needed for transfer
from a given stagedirectory => fix linefeeds, createremote, deleteremote, fail if stagedir empty ... etc.
Macrodef is using ant addon [Flaka](https://github.com/orgbitio/ant-flaka), if you don't need all that bells and whistles, simply use [sshexec task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sshexec.html) with `mkdir -p`
before scp to create your remote targetdir.

```
<project xmlns:fl="antlib:it.haefelinger.flaka">

<fl:install-property-handler/>

<macrodef name="scptransfer">
 <attribute name="host" default="${aix.host}"/>
 <attribute name="userid" default="${aix.userid}"/>
 <attribute name="knownhosts" default="${aix.knownhosts}"/>
 <attribute name="ppk" default="${aix.ppk}"/>
 <attribute name="createremote" default="false"/>
 <attribute name="remotedir" default="${eartarget}/${project}/${env}/${module}/${job.id}"/>
 <attribute name="deleteremote" default="false"/>
 <attribute name="deleteincludes" default="*"/>
 <attribute name="stagedir" default="${artifactdir}/${module}"/>
 <attribute name="stageincludes" default="**/*.*"/>
 <attribute name="stageexcludes" default=""/>
 <attribute name="failstageempty" default="true"/>
 <attribute name="fixLF" default="false"/>
 <attribute name="timeout" default="900000"/>
 <attribute name="verbose" default="true"/>

 <sequential>
   <echo>
   =============== SCP Transfer ===============
    Project          = ${project}
    Environment      = ${env}

    UserID           = @{userid}
    Targetserver     = @{host}
    Targetpath       = @{remotedir}
    fixLF ?          = @{fixLF}
    createremote ?   = @{createremote}
    deleteremote ?   = @{deleteremote}
    #{@{deleteremote} ? 'deleteincludes   = @{deletecincludes}' : '' }
    Stagedir         = @{stagedir}
    stageincludes    = @{stageincludes}
    stageexcludes    = @{stageexcludes}
   =============== SCP Transfer ===============
   </echo>
   <!-- contents in stagedir ? -->
   <resourcecount property="stagecount">
    <fileset dir="@{stagedir}" includes="@{stageincludes}" excludes="@{stageexcludes}" id="stagecontents"/>
   </resourcecount>
     <fl:choose>
       <fl:when test=" ${stagecount} > 0 ">
         <!-- Fix Linefeeds for ASCII Files -->
         <fl:when test=" @{fixLF} ">
           <fixcrlf
             excludes="**/*.jar **/*.tar **/*.zip **/*.ear **/*.class"
             srcdir="@{stagedir}"
             eol="lf"
             eof="remove"
             fixlast="true"
           />
         </fl:when>
         <!-- // T i m e o u t -->
         <parallel threadcount="1" timeout="@{timeout}">
           <!-- create remotedir ? -->
           <fl:when test=" @{createremote} ">
             <sshexec host="@{host}"
                  username="@{userid}"
                  knownhosts="@{knownhosts}"
                  keyfile="@{ppk}"
                  command="mkdir -p @{remotedir}"
             />
           </fl:when>
           <!-- delete contents in remotedir ?
            will throw error if remotedir doesn't exist ! -->
           <fl:when test=" @{deleteremote} ">
             <sshexec host="@{host}"
                  username="@{userid}"
                  knownhosts="@{knownhosts}"
                  keyfile="@{ppk}"
                  command="cd @{remotedir};rm -rfe @{delfilepattern}"
             />
           </fl:when>
           <!-- Filetransfer from stagedir -->
           <scp todir="@{userid}@@@{host}:@{remotedir}"
                keyfile="@{ppk}"
                knownhosts="@{knownhosts}"
                sftp="true"
                verbose="@{verbose}"
           >
             <fileset refid="stagecontents"/>
           </scp>
         </parallel>
         <!-- T i m e o u t // -->
       </fl:when>
       <fl:otherwise>
         <echo>
         =============== SCP Transfer =============
               Skip => NO StageDirContents !!
         =============== SCP Transfer =============
         </echo>
         <fl:fail message="Stagedir [@{stagedir}] empty !!" test=" @{failstageempty} "/>
       </fl:otherwise>
     </fl:choose>
 </sequential>
</macrodef>

</project>
```

As we switched to Github only recently get the manual [here](https://code.google.com/p/flaka/wiki/Manual) and some examples [here](https://code.google.com/p/flaka/wiki/FlakaExamples).

Answer (score 4):

You can use [sshexec](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sshexec.html) to create directories tree on remote machine before coping.
mkdir -p creates directories if not exists.
([How to mkdir only if a dir does not already exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793858/how-to-mkdir-only-if-a-dir-does-not-already-exist))

```
<sshexec
    host="${host}"
    username="${remote_user}"
    password="${remote_password}"
    command="mkdir -p ${remote_dir_path}"
    trust="true" />
```

Add it to your target before scp