# Move similar filenames to dir - Bash

Tags: bash

I have several images with `ID-sequence.jpg` name where ID is same for a group of images, for example:

```
4fd-00027-1.jpg
4fd-00027-2.jpg
4fd-00027-3.jpg
6gq-00017-1.jpg
6gq-00017-2.jpg
6gq-00752-3.jpg
6gq-00752-4.jpg
```

... now I need to move all those files into their own directories which should also be named the same as `ID`. I believe I need something like this:

```
for FILE in *; do
ID_REGEX="(.*(?=-))"
if [[ $FILE =~ $ID_REGEX ]]; then
  ID="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
  echo "$ID"
  mkdir -p "/Users/myname/images_organized/$ID"
  $(mv "/Users/myname/images/$FILE" "/Users/myname/images_organized/$ID/$FILE" )
fi
done
```

... but its not doing anything. No errors either.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to mkdir only if a dir does not already exist?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/793858/how-to-mkdir-only-if-a-dir-does-not-already-exist)

Comment: Ah thanks, knew about it but didn't think. But my code still doesn't move the files.

Comment: Do you know the bash `-x` option to print the script flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too much work.

```
for file in *
do
  dir="${file%%-*}"
  [ -d "$dir" ] || mkdir "$dir"
  mv "$file" "$dir"
done
```

Comment: hmm.. naming issue: `mv: rename /Users/myname/images_500ge2/77-52133-205.jpg to /Users/myname/images_organized/77/77-52133-205.jpg: No such file or directory`

Comment: No, the ID in this case is `77-52133` (last occurence of `-`)

Comment: Ah, *last* occurrence means use `%` instead of `%%`.