# Is it possible to check if a folder exists inside a shell command running in exec?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to create a oneliner in node using exec. The idea is to create a folder called *admin* and unzip untar a file into it, so:

```
mkdir admin
tar xvfz release.tar.gz -C admin/
```

The problem is, sometimes *admin* exists (its ok, I want to overwrite it contents), and that using exec will trigger an error:

```
exec('mkdir admin && tar xvfz release.tar.gz -C admin/', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
  if(err) { //mkdir fails when the folder exist }
});
```

Is there a way to elegantly continue if mkdir fails? Ideally, I want to clean the contents of admin like rm -rf admin/ so the new untar start fresh, but then again, that command will fail.

PS: I know I can check with FS for the folder before lunching exec, but Im interested on an all in one exec solution. (if possible)

EDIT: The question [How to mkdir only if a dir does not already exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793858) is similar but it is about the specific use of mkdir alone, this instead is about concatenation and error propagation.

Comment: @GhostCat please check my edit :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to have [`mkdir`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mkdir) fail on an existing target, you can use the `--parents` flag:

```
-p, --parents
no error if existing, make parent directories as needed
```

turning your oneliner into:

```
exec('mkdir -p admin && tar xvfz release.tar.gz -C admin/', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
  // continue
});
```

---

Alternatively, you could also use `;` instead of `&&` to chain the calls which will **always** continue, no matter the exit code:

```
exec('mkdir admin; tar xvfz release.tar.gz -C admin/', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
  // continue
});
```