# Trying to convert for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ... to SHELL

Tags: bash, shell, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to convert a [whole BATCH](https://github.com/cosote/R216-Z/blob/master/R216-Z_patch/R216-Z_patch.bat) script to SHELL script with the help of this sort of [converter manual](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/dosbatch.html).

I have almost finished, but I am struggling to convert this FOR LOOP:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('%adb% shell mkdir /usr/ui/^|find /i "File exists"') do (
    if not errorlevel 1 goto :cannot_patch
)
```

I know that [`for /f`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) is

> Loop command: against a set of files - conditionally perform a command against each item.

However, as I am a noob to SHELL SCRIPT (and BASH as well), my best try was:

```
for -f "tokens=*" a in ( '$ADB shell mkdir /usr/ui/^|find /i "File exists"' ); do
    if [ $? -nq 1 ]
    then
        cannot_patch
    fi
done
```

which does not work, resulting in a `Syntax error: Bad for loop variable`.

Any hint, link, or suggestion would be very much appreciated.

**EDIT**

I am trying to understand what exactly `('%adb% shell mkdir /usr/ui/^|find /i "File exists"')` is doing.

I thought those were sh commands, but it turns out I was wrong and that `find /i` is trying to

> Search(ing) for a text string in a file & display all the lines where it is found.

(https://ss64.com/nt/find.html)

`|` is the pipe operator and `"File exists"` [should be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793858/how-to-mkdir-only-if-a-directory-does-not-already-exist) the error thrown by `mkdir` in case the command tries to create a directory that already exists.

So I think I could probably write this easier, but still, what does the `^` symbol in `/usr/ui/^` do? Is it a regex?

**EDIT2**

It seems indeed that **@glenn_jackman** is right: probably I'd better understand what the code is trying to do.

So to give a better context, here is a bit more code of the original batch:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('%adb% shell mkdir /usr/ui/^|find /i "File exists"') do (
    if not errorlevel 1 goto :cannot_patch
)
:cannot_patch
echo Error: Cannot create directory!
echo Patch is already installed or system files exist and might be overwritten.
choice /m "Do you want to continue"
if errorlevel 2 goto :END
goto :continue_patch
```

To my understanding, the code is trying to run the `adb shell mkdir` command and, if it fails (throwing the "File exists" error), it will ask to the user if he/she wants to continue regardless.

So in this case, I guess the real problem is trying to write a code that does the same in SH, probably without the need of a for loop.

Still, I am finding it out...

Comment: The `for /F` loop is there to capture the output of the command line `%adb% shell mkdir /usr/ui/|find /i "File exists"`; not sure, but isn't there the `$` operator for such things?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It makes sense to use the `$` operator "somewhere". But...I sincerely don't know where exaclty I am suppose to place it...
Also, I don't know how to replace the `"tokens=*"` option.

Comment: This smells like an XY problem: Take a step back and describe what you want to do. It looks like you want to call `$ADB shell mkdir ...` and then do something if the directory already exists. If that's the case, then in sh or bash you don't need a for loop at all. I don't know CMD very well, but it seems that the CMD `for` command is designed to do tons of stuff beyond just iterating over a list of things.

Comment: Exactly! please, see my edit to see that I came to the same hypothesis of not using a for loop (or at least, simplify the code, I am still trying to understand it so please forgive me).
From the lines following this in the main code (I'll add this as well to my question) I read `echo Patch is already installed or system files exist and might be overwritten.`, so this is what I am testing.

Comment: If `%adb% shell mkdir /usr/ui/` is just there to create a directory, why not just suppress an error message and go on? like in `cmd`, you would do `mkdir "D:\some\path" 2> nul`…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('%adb% shell mkdir /usr/ui/^|find /i "File exists"') do (
    if not errorlevel 1 goto :cannot_patch
)
```

runs the command `%adb% shell mkdir /usr/ui/` then searches that output for the string `File exists`. `if not errorlevel 1` means "if %errorlevel% is not greater than or equal to 1," which is a weird and awkward way of just saying `if "%errorlevel%"=="0"`, which would mean that the string was found. If it's found, the script then goes to the label `:cannot_patch`.

In bash, the way to process the output of a command is to use `$()` instead of `for /f`, so

```
$(${adb} shell mkdir /usr/ui/ | grep "File exists") && cannot_patch
```

This assumes that the variable `adb` is set and you've got a function in your shell script somewhere called `cannot_patch`.

Note that the only difference between my answer and [Paul Hodge's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64717798/4158862) is that I'm assuming that you still need `ADB` to be called.

Comment: Thanks! I edited the question inserting a link to the complete batch script I am trying to covert. Yes, indeed ADB is needed as it connects to the router I am trying to patch. I will let you know asap what I will achieve using your suggestions!

Comment: I actually solved differently but yours and others answers really helped me a lot. Sorry for replying so late. a link to what I did: https://github.com/umbe1987/R216-Z/blob/c49708deabba80b433c2a24680dd98adcda0eca1/R216-Z_patch/R216-Z_patch.sh#L105-L110

Answer (score 1):

The general syntax of your loop matches https://ss64.com/nt/for.html
You should also look over https://ss64.com/nt/errorlevel.html and [this SO reference that lists/explains error codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34987885/what-are-the-errorlevel-values-set-by-internal-cmd-exe-commands/34987886#34987886).

From the SO article, `FOR /F │ 1 = No data was processed.`
But the errorlevel page says

```
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 will return TRUE whether the errorlevel is 1 or 5 or 64
```

and the SO article also says

```
if %errorlevel% equ 5 (
    echo Can not access the directory, check rights
)
```

Apparently `^` is a CMD escape character, used here to escape the pipe character being passed as part of a compound command that (I'm guessing...) creates a directory and checks for a failure, so I'm parsing this as an attempt to make the directory, detect if it already exists, and respond accordingly.

I think in bash this would be written this way:

```
mkdir /usr/ui/ || cannot_patch
```

Comment: I'm reading `if not errorlevel 1` as a lazy way of writing `if "!errorlevel!"=="0"`, but I usually don't mess with errorelevel beyond "0" and "not 0".

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but I have got bad news for you — the batch code you want to transcript is wrong:

```cmd
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('%adb% shell mkdir /usr/ui/^|find /i "File exists"') do (
    if not errorlevel 1 goto :cannot_patch
)
```

This is not going to do what you probably think it does. The following steps actually happen:

- It executes the command `%adb% shell mkdir /usr/ui/` and pipes (`|`) its output into the command `find /i "File exists"`, but all this happens in a new `cmd.exe` instance created by the `for /F` loop.
- The `for /F` loop, well, loops over the lines of the output of the aforesaid commands after they have completed; the new `cmd.exe` instance is destroyed before starting to iterate.
- **BUT:** The `ErrorLevel` value resulting from the `%adb% …|find …` command line is **not** available in the body of the `for /F` loop, because this executes in the `cmd.exe` instance the batch script itself runs in too. This means, that the condition `if not errorlevel 1` in the loop body actually reacts on a *preceding* command, unintentionally.

Since, as I believe, you simply want to test whether the output of `%adb% shell mkdir /usr/ui/` contains the sub-string `File exists` in a case-insensitive manner, you actually just need this:

```cmd
rem /* Just using `echo` for demonstration purposes, to be replaced;
rem    moreover, you may also omit the `&&` or the `||` part: */
%adb% shell mkdir /usr/ui/ | find /i "File exists" && (
    echo ErrorLevel 0: sub-string found.
) || (
    echo ErrorLevel 1: sub-string NOT found!
)
```

Unfortunately, I cannot tell you exactly how to translate this, but `find` might probably have to be substituted by `grep`, and the operators `&&` and `||` could be replaced by checking the exit code returned in `$?`, unless there are similar operators…

Comment: `&&` and `||` are the same in both batch and bash, fortunately