# Make a folder for once in bash

Tags: bash

I need a bash script which will find a folder named "Test" in a directory. If it's present there it willn't make the folder named "Test" otherwise it will make a folder named "Test" in the directory.
Tried ifs, if, for loop but in vain.

Comment: `mkdir -p Test` will create it if it doesn't exist and won't create it if it exists - without complaining.

Comment: See: [How to mkdir only if a directory does not already exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/793858/3776858)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to mkdir only if a directory does not already exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793858/how-to-mkdir-only-if-a-directory-does-not-already-exist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code you're probably looking for (pretty basic):

```
folder="Test"
dir="d"
if [[ !(-e $dir/$folder) ]];then 
mkdir $dir/$folder
fi
```

-e operator, checks if thats anything as name="Test".