# Share variables of GitHub Actions job to multiple subsequent jobs while retaining specific order

Tags: github, github-actions

We have [a GitHub Actions workflow](https://github.com/jonashackt/tekton-argocd-eks/blob/main/.github/workflows/provision.yml) consiting of 3 jobs:

1. `provision-eks-with-pulumi`: Provisions AWS EKS cluster (using Pulumi here)
2. `install-and-run-argocd-on-eks`: Installing & configuring ArgoCD using `kubeconfig` from **job 1.**
3. `install-and-run-tekton-on-eks`: Installing & running Tekton using `kubeconfig` from **job 1.**, but depending on **job 2.**

We are already aware [of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61236803/4964553) and [the docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idoutputs) and use `jobs.<jobs_id>.outputs` to define the variable in job 1. and `jobs.<job_id>.needs.` to use the variable in the subsequent jobs. BUT it only works for our job 2. - but failes for job 3.. Here's our workflow.yml:

```
name: provision

on: [push]

env:
  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
  AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: 'eu-central-1'

jobs:
  provision-eks-with-pulumi:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      PULUMI_ACCESS_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.PULUMI_ACCESS_TOKEN }}
    outputs:
      kubeconfig: ${{ steps.pulumi-up.outputs.kubeconfig }}
    steps:
      ...

      - name: Provision AWS EKS cluster with Pulumi
        id: pulumi-up
        run: |
          pulumi stack select dev
          pulumi up --yes

          echo "Create ~/.kube dir only, if not already existent (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/793867/4964553)"
          mkdir -p ~/.kube

          echo "Create kubeconfig and supply it for depending Action jobs"
          pulumi stack output kubeconfig > ~/.kube/config
          echo "::set-output name=kubeconfig::$(pulumi stack output kubeconfig)"

      - name: Try to connect to our EKS cluster using kubectl
        run: kubectl get nodes

  install-and-run-argocd-on-eks:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: provision-eks-with-pulumi
    environment:
      name: argocd-dashboard
      url: ${{ steps.dashboard-expose.outputs.dashboard_host }}
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@master

      - name: Configure kubeconfig to use with kubectl from provisioning job
        run: |
          mkdir ~/.kube
          echo '${{ needs.provision-eks-with-pulumi.outputs.kubeconfig }}' > ~/.kube/config
          echo "--- Checking connectivity to cluster"
          kubectl get nodes

      - name: Install ArgoCD
        run: ...


  install-and-run-tekton-on-eks:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: install-and-run-argocd-on-eks
    environment:
      name: tekton-dashboard
      url: ${{ steps.dashboard-expose.outputs.dashboard_host }}
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@master

      - name: Configure kubeconfig to use with kubectl from provisioning job
        run: |
          mkdir ~/.kube
          echo '${{ needs.provision-eks-with-pulumi.outputs.kubeconfig }}' > ~/.kube/config
          echo "--- Checking connectivity to cluster"
          kubectl get nodes

      - name: Install Tekton Pipelines, Dashboard, Triggers
        run: ...
```

The first job gets the `kubeconfig` correctly using `needs.provision-eks-with-pulumi.outputs.kubeconfig` - but the second job does not (see [this GitHub Actions log](https://github.com/jonashackt/tekton-argocd-eks/actions/runs/1876245000)). We also don't want our 3. job to only depend on job 1., because then job 2. and 3. will run in parallel.

**How could our job 3. run after job 2. - but use the variables with the `kubeconfig` from job 1.?**

Comment: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/25634

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's easy, because [a GitHub Actions job can depend on multiple jobs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/using-jobs-in-a-workflow#defining-prerequisite-jobs) using the `needs` keyword. All you have to do in job 3. is to use an array notation like `needs: [job1, job2]`.

So for your workflow it will look like this:

```
name: provision

on: [push]

env:
  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
  AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: 'eu-central-1'

jobs:
  provision-eks-with-pulumi:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      PULUMI_ACCESS_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.PULUMI_ACCESS_TOKEN }}
    outputs:
      kubeconfig: ${{ steps.pulumi-up.outputs.kubeconfig }}
    steps:
      ...

      - name: Provision AWS EKS cluster with Pulumi
        id: pulumi-up
        run: |
          pulumi stack select dev
          pulumi up --yes

          echo "Create ~/.kube dir only, if not already existent (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/793867/4964553)"
          mkdir -p ~/.kube

          echo "Create kubeconfig and supply it for depending Action jobs"
          pulumi stack output kubeconfig > ~/.kube/config
          echo "::set-output name=kubeconfig::$(pulumi stack output kubeconfig)"

      - name: Try to connect to our EKS cluster using kubectl
        run: kubectl get nodes

  install-and-run-argocd-on-eks:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: provision-eks-with-pulumi
    env:
      name: argocd-dashboard
      url: ${{ steps.dashboard-expose.outputs.dashboard_host }}
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@master

      - name: Configure kubeconfig to use with kubectl from provisioning job
        run: |
          mkdir ~/.kube
          echo '${{ needs.provision-eks-with-pulumi.outputs.kubeconfig }}' > ~/.kube/config
          echo "--- Checking connectivity to cluster"
          kubectl get nodes

      - name: Install ArgoCD
        run: ...


  install-and-run-tekton-on-eks:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [provision-eks-with-pulumi, install-and-run-argocd-on-eks]
    env:
      name: tekton-dashboard
      url: ${{ steps.dashboard-expose.outputs.dashboard_host }}
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@master

      - name: Configure kubeconfig to use with kubectl from provisioning job
        run: |
          mkdir ~/.kube
          echo '${{ needs.provision-eks-with-pulumi.outputs.kubeconfig }}' > ~/.kube/config
          echo "--- Checking connectivity to cluster"
          kubectl get nodes

      - name: Install Tekton Pipelines, Dashboard, Triggers
        run: ...
```

Comment: I don't know why this answer is -1 : it's a good anwser.
Event if job3 needs job2, and job2 needs job1, you HAVE to add `needs: [*job1*,job2]` in job3 to access a variable from job1 with `${{ needs.job1.outputs.whatever }}`

Comment: Thats true. And you're welcome to vote up :)

Comment: This approach should be used with caution, due to the `echo` commands in the subsequent steps outputting the full contents of the kubeconfig to the workflow logs, which in a public repository will be publicly accessible. In OP's case, credentials are not stored in the kubeconfig, but in others', they may be.