# Is there a way to check for dir with ls and then create an directory with just one commmand?

Tags: shell, command, ls, mkdir

I'm quite new to shell commands and wondered if there is a way to connect two commands:
Scenario-> you check for a directory with the command ls and if it isn't there yet you connect ls with the command mkdir.

Can you connect those two? I tried ls  && mkdir

Thanks for any tips and any Help!

I tried to check if there is the directory bar in my path, if not it should create one named bar. the commands should look something like that: ls bar && mkdir bar

The output of that tho is ls: bar not found . bcs obviously it wasn't created yet.

Comment: You can try `mkdir -p bar`

Comment: thanks a lot, i figured a pipe would do the job so ls bar | mkdir bar is it

Comment: `ls` is the wrong tool to test if a directory exists.  If you want to test that the directory `foo` exists, use `test -d foo`.  But in this case, you don't really want to bother checking if the directory exists; just attempt to create it with `mkdir -p foo`.  Even if you do test and write `test -d foo || mkdir foo`, you have introduced a classic race condition; the test determines that `foo` does not exist, but some other process creates it before the `mkdir` is executed.

Comment: Shell command questions belong on [unix.se] or [ubuntu.se]., This site is for programming-related questions only. You can find more information in the [help].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`&&` only executes the second command if the first was not successful - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510640/what-is-the-purpose-of-in-a-shell-command). For the command `ls bar && mkdir bar`, if `bar` does not exist, the `ls bar` will be unsuccessful and it will not continue to the `mkdir bar`.

You could use `ls bar || mkdir bar` instead of the `&&` to make sure the second command executes, even if the first did not successfully finish.

A better option if you are not sure if `bar` exists would be `mkdir -p bar && ls bar`. `mkdir -p bar` will make `bar` if it does not exist, and will not throw an error if `bar` already exists (explained better in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793858/how-to-mkdir-only-if-a-directory-does-not-already-exist)). Then, you know the directory exists by the time you call `ls`, and so you are confident `ls` will successfully complete. If there is nothing in the folder, you know it was newly created, and if there are contents, you know it already existed.